# Simplify using Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I can simplify this using Kmaps, but can't figure out how to using boolean algebra. If anyone could show me the steps I'd really appreciate it.

\$F = \bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z} + xy + x\bar{z}\$

should simplify to:

\$F= xy + y\bar{z}\$

Comment: sorry, fixed with edit

Comment: The site supports [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org) so I added it to your equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the identities: \$a+\bar{a} = 1\$ and \$a+1 = 1\$

\$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}+x\bar{z}+xy\$

\$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}+x\bar{z}(y+\bar{y})+xy\$

\$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}+x\bar{z}y+x\bar{z}\bar{y}+xy\$

\$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}+x\bar{z}\bar{y}+x\bar{z}y+xy\$

\$(\bar{x}+x)\bar{y}\bar{z}+(\bar{z}+1)xy\$

\$\bar{y}\bar{z}+xy\$